# .NET equivalent DataTable and Dataset in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, macos

What is .NET equivalent DataTable and DataSet in objective-C? is NameTable & NSMutableArray is correct option or any other like NSSet? What is correct? please give me direction. Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not DataTable or DataSet equivalent in Objective C.
I use combination of NSArray/NSMutableArray and NSDictionary/NSMutableDictionaty.

You can create NSArray which keeps your data (table data) and NSDictionary to keep single data row, for example:

```
NSDictionary *person1 = @{@"Name" : @"John", @"Age" : @(25)};
NSDictionary *person2 = @{@"Name" : @"Nick", @"Age" : @(21)};
NSArray *personTable = @[person1, person2];
```

This is just an example and you can change it to keep NSDictionary embedded in NSDictionary or NSArray embedded in NSDictionary, etc. It depends what works better for you.